# django user authentication incorporated with models and views

Tags: python, django

I still cant seem to put a simple program together.  I am thinking of a simple program where my coworkers and I could propose a bet with each other. (example:  I bet the detriot Lions dont win another game this season)  If someone is feeling up to the task of taking that bet they can just hit an accept button.  I want the user to be logged in and upon submitting the bet_name and bet_desc of the bet, their username, bet_name, bet_desc, and timestamp is saved to a table.  Then a relationship table would save the bet id, win, tie, created_user_id, accepted_user_id, accepted_timestamp, and cancelled.  Then userprofile table to keep their username, wins, losses, ties, bets_made, and bets_accepted.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime



class UserProfiles(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User)
    wins = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    losses = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    ties = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    bets_made = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)  
    bets_accepted = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)      

    def __str__(self):
         return "%s's profile" % self.username

class Bets2(models.Model):
    bet_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    bet_desc = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_user = models.OneToOneField(UserProfiles, primary_key=True)
    accepted_user = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    accepted_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    win = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    tie = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    cancelled = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s's profile" % self.bet_name
```

As far as forms.py and views this is all i have so far:

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from .models import Bets2, UserProfiles

class BetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bets2
        fields = ['bet_name', 'bet_desc',]

        def clean_name(self):
            bet_name = self.cleaned_data.get('bet_name')
        #write code here
            return name

        def clean_bet(self):
            bet_desc = self.cleaned_data.get('bet_desc')
        #write code here
            return bet
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings

from .forms import BetForm
from .models import Bets2, UserProfiles


def home(request):
    title = "2015 Boardbets"
    queryset = Bets2.objects.all().order_by('timestamp')
    queryuser = UserProfiles.objects.all()
    context = {
    "title": title,
    "queryset" : queryset,
    "queryuser" : queryuser, 
    }
    return render(request, "home.html", context)

def boardbet(request):
    form = BetForm(request.POST or None) 
    bet_variables = Bets2.objects.all()
    context = {
    "form" : form,
    "bet_variables" : bet_variables,
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    return render(request, "bets.html", context)
```

This is where i get stumped, i dont know how to incorporate the other two models into the view so that all three tables get created and also how to reference them in the template.

Edit: changed it to one model for Bets

Comment: It sounds like you're expecting your form to do too much. Imo, you should just have a list of bets and then have an accept button that a logged in user can use to accept it

Comment: why did you need AcceptedBet and Bet as a separated model?

Comment: I was trying to show a relationship table with bets as a 1to1 and show the details of the bet such as winner, but I can try to do it in one model.

Comment: Also did I do the relationship from the bets to user and user profile to user correctly? I feel like I should 1to1 UserProfiles  to user and then many to many created_user and accepted_user to UserProfiles